# Firebase Authentication UI 1.1.1: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have problem with add Firebase Authenttication UI to my app. I added dependecies to my app gradle file and Fabric repository like [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md).I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.> Manifest
>   merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

**app.gradle(app)**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.learnwords"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**app.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.learnwords">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AddYourWords" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Navigation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FragmentOne"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_one"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Learning"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Where is it? @MichaelMeyer

Comment: For anyone that is still coming here, I was also figuring out where the log was. It refers to the `gradle console` bottom right in android studio. There I found clear error messages that got me solving my specific issue manifest merger error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the manifest merge problems is likely caused by `android:supportsRtl="true"`. Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to include the tools namespace:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.app.package"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

And then add the override for `supportsRTL`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

This issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/520).

Post the build output to show all the errors to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

add both in app level gradle you are missing **core**.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
```

Add **google-services.json** file downloaded from firebase server in app level.

Add **internet permission** in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I adde core to app.gradle(app). I still have error. JSON file and internet permission is correct.

Comment: I have google-service.json. Firebase Database working